# Is it possible to use Google Docs API to convert text string to PDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, google-docs-api

Recently I found, that Google Docs have their own [PHP API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html). Honestly I haven't read it all, but I wonder is it possible If for example I have XML file or just text string in variable and I would like to convert it and create PDF file from it ( for example ), then would it be possible? Or even if it is possible it would take a lot of time to process?

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you know that you don't need Google Docs to make a pdf using php?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

Comment: Yes, I know. I know, that there's many different libraries for that purpose, but most of them aren't automated. Some of them need to hursh html template representation and some of them are just *$* which is not an option in open source world, but if google docs api is same as loading `*.txt` file and then downloading it as `*.pdf` (like in google docs), then it definitely has a plus from me.

Comment: @Jeff Also I forgot to mansion, that on most shared servers you can't install extensions with PECL. At least from my experience. And if I'm not mistaking, then exactly this http://www.pdflib.com/ library isn't free.

Comment: Why don't you look into http://www.fpdf.org/ ? It looks like it's free and you don't need to install any extensions.

Comment: @Jeff I will take it into consideration, but I'm interested at the moment in google docs api possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.
Slightly time consuming as you will have to format the PDF.. 
I suggest using a class like FPDF or EZPDF, to create the PDF output from PHP.